# SQL SET statement

Tags: select, set, sql

I am currently improving my knowledge of SQL. Currently I am trying to declare a variable by getting a value from a select statement. First Question: Is this possible?

Second Question: I have this SQL attempting to do the above. My intension is to set `@version_group` to whatever `version_replace` holds, which is always a single row, single column result.

```
    DECLARE @version_group int
    SET @version_group = SELECT version_replace FROM users WHERE id=@sid
```

How can I correct this to valid syntax? (assuming it's possible)

Comment: -1 to self for missing from statement in posted query!

Comment: Fell free to edit your question

Comment: Your knowledge of SQL should include that it is a set-based language (pun intended) and is intended to work with an optimizer. You appear to be using SQL to write procedural code. Once you have the `@version_group` value, what are you going to do with it? If the answer is, "Use it as a parameter in another SQL statement," then consider combining the two and giving the optimizer a proper look at things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I correct this to valid
>   syntex? (assuming it's possible)

The syntax you want is as follows, it needs one piece of info that you don't have in your original effort though (the FROM clause) :

```
DECLARE @version_group int

select @version_group = version_replace from (you're missing this from your query) where id=@sid
```

Comment: tick for being first! (I need multiple ticks)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible. Just do (SQL 2008):

```
declare @version_group as int=
(SELECT version_replace 
FROM users
WHERE id=@sid);
```

Comment: +1 but worth noting its valid in SQL 2k8 only (and the AS is optional)

Comment: I guess you are right :(   I work with SQL 2k8 and this is the syntax I use.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @version_group int

SELECT @version_group = version_replace
FROM   MyVersionTable
WHERE  id=@sid
```

Don't forget to include your data source (i.e. table, view, replacing `MyVersionTable` above).

Answer (score 0):

1. Sure
2. `SELECT @version_group = version_replace FROM YourTable WHERE id=@sid`

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @version_group int

-- THEN

SET @version_group = 1

-- OR!

SELECT @version_group FROM version_replace WHERE id=@sid
```